# Can i use Google app script for developing google chrome extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

Can we publish google app-script code in to a chrome extension tool. So far we developed a web app from app-script, which is working as a web application. What need to be done to convert it in to a chrome extension from google app-script Editor. Appreciations are shared for valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've developed both GAS Web Apps and Chrome Extensions and I can say with certainty that you cannot use Google Apps Script's GUI editor to develop a Chrome extension. They are two very different beasts.

For one, Google Apps Script, uses its own flavor of server-side javascript. Plus it leverages libraries and services unique to its platform.

A Chrome extension uses client-side javascript and it too has its own libraries and services.

Moreover, they handle user authentication a bit differently (even though they are leveraging the same OAuth2 flows under the hood).

But you might be able to integrate the two. You should be able to make POST requests to a Web App from a Chrome Extension, so that's one approach.

However GAS scripts are limited by quota restrictions so you might be better off rebuilding your app from the ground up as a self-contained Chrome Extension (the better option in my opinion).