# Use Google apps script in Chrome extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

We want to write a chrome extension to add calendar events based on sheets data.
(Customer needs to choose between list of projects to add to the calendar)

It should be really easy if we can get the data from the sheet with Google apps script. How can we use Google apps script in the extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use Google app script for developing google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425363/can-i-use-google-app-script-for-developing-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Consider creating a Sheets Add-on instead of an extension.